# check if a pandas df index is having time within last 30 minutes or not(UTC time)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame in the below format:-

The index is in DateTime index format and is sorted and the interval is 15 minutes. I want to check if the data frame index is having a DateTime index range within the last 30 minutes or not. (UTC time).

sample code:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time','col1','col2'])# Add records to dataframe using the .loc functiondf.loc[0] = [2014,"toyota","corolla"] 
df.loc[1] = ['2021-03-10 17:15:00+00:00',"honda","civic"] 
df.loc[2] = ['2021-03-10 17:30:00+00:00',"honda","civic"] 
df.loc[3] = ['2021-03-10 17:45:00+00:00',"honda","civic"] 
df.set_index('time')
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample code, modify the last statement setting index as follows:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')
```

Then, to check whether the DateTime index range within the 30 minutes from now in UTC time, you can use:

```
((pd.Timestamp.now(tz='UTC') - df.index[-1]) / pd.Timedelta('1 minute')) < 30 

Output:
 
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to localize to your timezone

```
idx_max = df.index.max().tz_localize('America/Los_Angeles').tz_convert('UTC')
utc_30 = pd.Timestamp.utcnow() - pd.offsets.Minute(30)

idx_max > utc_30
```

If your index already has a timezone, then you can skip the `tz_localize`

```
idx_max = df.index.max().tz_convert('UTC')
utc_30 = pd.Timestamp.utcnow() - pd.offsets.Minute(30)

idx_max > utc_30
```

You can get a list of your possible timezones with

```
import pytz

pytz.country_timezones('US')
```

For whatever country you are in.

Comment: Why should the OP localize and then tz_convert? The input already has UTC offset specified as 00:00, which is parsed to UTC

Comment: Yeah. I didn’t realize that right away. That’s why I updated my answer to show what to do if it already has a time zone.